# Extend dojo HtmlStore to prevent it from only taking the text of a cell of the original table

Tags: javascript, dojo

I try to extend the  getValues() method of the dojox HtmlStore to prevent it from escaping HtmlTags of the original table, as I need them for my layout.
This is my first approach, however, it doesn't even find the appropriate class...

```
dojo.extend(dojox.data.HtmlStore, {
    getValues : function(/* item */item,
    /* attribute-name-string */attribute) {
        // summary:
        // See dojo.data.api.Read.getValues()

        this._assertIsItem(item);
        var index = this._assertIsAttribute(attribute);
        if (index > -1) {
            var text;
            if (item.cells) {
                text = xmlParser.innerXML(item.cells[index]);
            } else {// return Value for lists
                text = xmlParser.innerXML(item);
            }
            return [ this.trimWhitespace ? lang.trim(text) : text ];
        }
        return []; // Array
    }
});
```

What do I need to do?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use dojo.declare : http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/declare.html